# Vertical scrolling in row-wrapped flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am have been trying to. achieve vertical scrolling for two days as I am learning frontend development. (and I am using React for this, please forgive my syntax)

I have 3 main parts that i want to fill my viewport with:

- Navigation: A common header for the app
- Left-side content: Something fixed in size so I can programmatically scroll its content
- Right-side content: A vertically scrolling panel with its contents being row-wrapped

But the issue is that, whenever the height of the right-side content increases due to row-wrapping, the `<div id="right-side">` also increases in height despite the fact that I have given it height of 100% of its parent. This increase in height also affects up to `<div id="main-view">` and results in not only the entire page being scrolled, but also increasing the height of the `<div id="left-side">` which clips part of its content.

Here is my code that is **not** working

```
<div id="app" style={{height: '100%', display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'column'}}>   

    <div id="navigation-bar" style={{height: '50px', backgroundColor: '#ddddff', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        Navigation
    </div>

    <div id="main-view" style={{flex: 1, display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'row wrap'}}>

        <div id="left-side" style={{flex: 3, display: 'flex'}}>
            <div id="should-not-expand" style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#dddddd'}} />
        </div>

        <div id="right-side" style={{flex: 2, display: 'flex', height: '100%', maxHeight: '100%', minHeight: '100%'}}>
            <div id="should-vertically-scroll" style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ffdddd', display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'column', overflowY: 'scroll'}}>

                <div id="heading" style={{margin: '30px 30px 0 30px', backgroundColor: '#ddffdd'}}>
                    Header
                </div>

                <div id="expandable-height" style={{margin: '25px', display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'row wrap'}}>
                    <div style={{margin: '5px', height: '150px', width: '200px', backgroundColor: '#fff'}} />
                    <div style={{margin: '5px', height: '150px', width: '200px', backgroundColor: '#fff'}} />
                    <div style={{margin: '5px', height: '150px', width: '200px', backgroundColor: '#fff'}} />
                    <div style={{margin: '5px', height: '150px', width: '200px', backgroundColor: '#fff'}} />
                    <div style={{margin: '5px', height: '150px', width: '200px', backgroundColor: '#fff'}} />
                    <div style={{margin: '5px', height: '150px', width: '200px', backgroundColor: '#fff'}} />
                    <div style={{margin: '5px', height: '150px', width: '200px', backgroundColor: '#fff'}} />
                    <div style={{margin: '5px', height: '150px', width: '200px', backgroundColor: '#fff'}} />
                    <div style={{margin: '5px', height: '150px', width: '200px', backgroundColor: '#fff'}} />
                    <div style={{margin: '5px', height: '150px', width: '200px', backgroundColor: '#fff'}} />
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What I tried**

For some reason, I have tried giving the `<div id="expandable-height">` a fixed height of 0px. And it did cause the scrolls to be contained within the right side. However, this workaround seemed like a bad solution since I would not be able to place a footer after the `<div id="expandable-height">`, it would simply overlap with the row-wrapped contents.

It would be a priceless lesson to learn what is going on, and what is possible vs. what is not. I really appreciate your time and consideration! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root" />
</body>

</html>
```

index.css

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', 'Roboto', 'Oxygen', 'Ubuntu', 'Cantarell', 'Fira Sans', 'Droid Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#root {
    height: 100%;
}

code {
    font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace;
}
```

index.tsx

```
// imports

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root')!);
```

Comment: Give a full HTML code including script link.

Comment: Flex is working correctly there - the viewport height will change as the row wrap takes effect. You could control the wrapping behavior by using fixed widths on the flex children that correspond to media query breakpoints. For example, each flex child is 500px and then when the viewport hits 500px, you change the width to 250px such that the children now stack. Viewport will still change in height but you could manage that more fully.

Comment: It's also very tricky to use fixed pixel heights on parent elements for the exact reason you mention: when things change, they will automatically overflow their containers. HTML is always trying to display content, so you can hide that behavior with `overflow-y: hidden;` but that's non ideal. Build interfaces that allow for content to create scrollable containers when it's needed.

Comment: @staypuftman thanks for the comments. I am still having hard time digesting what you explained. :( 
Do you suggest that I try to re-imagine a different route to achieving what I desire as the outcome?

Comment: @JunPark - seems like you want a very static interface so yes, you need to rethink a bit. Your layout isn't wrong necessarily but you haven't used the `position` property, which is required if you want things to be `position:fixed`, like that left column. But it's pretty weird to have two fixed columns with scrolling inside of each.

Comment: @staypuftman What I will be trying next is, giving the NavigationBar `position: fixed`, then fixing the two columns to `height: 100vh`. I will also give both columns `padding-top: 50px` since the height of the NavigationBar is the only constant and I feel ok reusing a constant. Also, I am not going to allow user scrolling of the left-side hehe, it will be done programmatically. Imagine a pokemon game screen, where there is a giant map with limited screen.

Comment: @JunPark - yeah then do everything with `position:fixed` and then make flexboxes inside of the fixed containers.